# Error code and dual code

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

From section 10.4.1 of Nielsen & Chuang's [Quantum Computation and Quantum Information](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511976667):

> Let $C$ be a linear code. Show that if $x\in C^{\perp}$ then $\sum_{y\in C}(-1)^{x\cdot y}=|C|$, while $x\notin C^{\perp}$ then $\sum_{y\in C}(-1)^{x\cdot y}=0$.

I don't understand how to solve it. The first part is pretty trivial, and for the second part it is clear to see that there must be $|C|/2$ elements that are not orthogonal to $x$ since there would be an equal amount of orthogonal and non-orthogonal elements resulting in $0$. Now I have looked around the internet and found the following solutions:

1. https://github.com/yquek/NielsenChuangSolutions/blob/master/Chapter%2010/NC%20Chapter%2010.pdf
2. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/112179/basic-classical-linear-error-correcting-code-for-bits-exercice-from-nielsen-c
3. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11729/identity-for-linear-codes-and-their-duals-why-do-we-have-sum-y-1x-cdot-y

However my problem is I cannot see the intuition they use. Is there someone who can really dumb down this?

Comment: http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if $x\notin C^{\perp}$ then ${x\cdot y}=x_1y_1+\cdots+x_n y_n=1\pmod 2$ so there is some coordinate, and relabel coordinates if necessary to assume that it is the first coordinate where $x_1 y_1=1$ which implies $x_1=1.$
So ${x\cdot y}=y_1+x_2y_2+\cdots+x_n y_n:=y_1+S(y_2,\ldots,y_n).$
Now break up the sum as follows
$$
\sum_{y\in C}(-1)^{x\cdot y}=
\sum_{y \in C: y_1=0} (-1)^{x\cdot y}+
\sum_{y \in C: y_1=0} (-1)^{x\cdot y}=
$$
or
$$
=\sum_{y \in C: y_1=0} (-1)^{0+S(y_2,\ldots,y_n)}+
\sum_{y \in C: y_1=1} (-1)^{1+S(y_2,\ldots,y_n)}=
$$
or
$$
=(-1)^{0} \sum_{y \in C: y_1=0} (-1)^{S(y_2,\ldots,y_n)}+
(-1)^1 \sum_{y \in C: y_1=1} (-1)^{S(y_2,\ldots,y_n)}
$$
and note that since the inner sums only depend on $y_2,\ldots,y_n$, we obtain zero.

*Note:* Since $C$ is linear, each $y_i$ takes on the values $0$ and $1$ an equal number of times. Therefore
$$
\#\{y \in C: y_1=0\}=\#\{y \in C: y_1=1\}
$$

Comment: What do you mean with "you can take out a +1 in the first sum and a -1 in the second giving zero."?

Comment: $(-1)^{a+b}=(-1)^a (-1)^b$ basic algebra

Comment: Ah okay, but I cannot see how we know that each sum have the same size. I am missing something trivial or? Why can't there be more $y\in C$ s.t. $y=1$ than $y\in C$ s.t. $y=0$?

Comment: The code $C$ is linear, so each coordinate $y_i$ of the code is balanced, i.e., it equals $0$ and $1$ an equal number of times. Apply this to $y_1$ to obtain the result.

Comment: "Since $C$ is linear, each $y_i$ takes on the values $0$ and $1$ an equal number of times." except for those $i$ such that $y_i$ has value $0$ in _all_ the codewords?